# Counting disk IO statistics for query

Tags: linux, postgresql

Using postrgresql. I know that `explain analyse` can be used to inspect where a query is spending time. Now would like to have the same execution plan (or at least a summary per query) showing how many bytes and how many continguous blocks were read to get the result. Is it possible to get this information? If not, is it possible to know the process ID used to execute a query?

While the process is alive I can get some of the information using `/proc/{pid}/io`, also I can get system wide information using iostat. Any help towards associating the disk usage with individual queries would be appreciated, if possible, couting also operations that hit operating system cache.

Thank you.

Comment: `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` will contain that information (after you set `track_io_timing` to `on`)

Comment: That's something, I see things like `Buffers: shared hit=5830 read=128303`, what is the unit of this? Any other things that can be logged, also, is it possible to log this with the queries in a production environment?